# How to make Java singleton from .form in IntellijIDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, singleton

The problem is to make singleton from Java class that was binded to .form in IntellijIDEA.

SSCCE: 
We need to create a swing GUI using IDEA tool "UI Designer" and make it a Singleton.

We already have a ServerFace.form that is binded to class ServerFace.java
We also have a class Index.java that makes the first initialization of ServerFace.

See the code of both classes below (there is no code in ServerFace.form):

ServerFace.java(class binded to ServerFace.form):

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class ServerFace {
    private JPanel panel1;
    private JButton startServerButton;
    private JButton stopServerButton;
    private JButton clearLogButton;
    private JTextArea textArea1;

//Make it Singleton--------------------------------------
    private static volatile ServerFace instance;

    public static ServerFace getInstance(){

        if (instance==null){
            synchronized (ServerFace.class){
                if(instance==null){
                    try{
                        instance=new ServerFace();
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        System.out.println("failed to create UI: "+e+"  |  "+e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return  instance;
    }

    private ServerFace() throws Exception{

    }
    private void createUIComponents() {
        // TODO: place custom component creation code here
    }
}
```

Index.java (class that gets instance of ServerFace.java):

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Index{

    private static ServerFace _gui;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        _gui = ServerFace.getInstance();
    }
}
```

When I try to compile it throws an Exception
"failed to create UI: java.lang.NullPointerException  |  null"

What I do wrong and how to get it right?

Comment: It seems that the `ServerFace` constructor fires a `NullPointerException`, are you showing us the full code?

Comment: there is a private constructor here: private ServerFace() throws Exception{

    }

Comment: I perfectly know that. But in the code you are showing us I can't see possibilities for throwing a `NullPointerException`, so is that your real code? If you removed the code that was in the constructor when you wrote the question, please add it

Comment: This class was automatically generated by IDEA and I only changed constructor attribute from public to private and add code to make it a singleton. This is a full real code.

Comment: Well, this code itself **can't** generate a `NullPointerException`. I cannot reproduce your error, so please make an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so that we can see what's going on there.

Comment: I've edited my question and added an SSCCE.

Comment: If this is really the full code, I think that your IntellijIDEA has some problem. This cose does not cause a `NullPointerException`. See [this working example](http://ideone.com/J4Xuz9). Try compiling it from command line, likely the `NullPointerException` will disappear.

Comment: Of course your example works because you don't use a binding form. But if you bind it to IDEA's UI Designer form it ends with NullPointerException. That is the problem I want to solve.

Comment: So the problem is related to IDEA, in that case I don't know how to help you, the code itself is fine. [Why don't you try building your form by hand?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/refining.html) It's not difficult.

Comment: BackSlash, thanks for feedback. Yes, I've already done it by hands there is no problem with it, but I think I'll try to found out a solution on idea community. I'll write here about results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution. The problem was that one of my components (panel1) had "custom create" flag but I didn't provide any code in createUIComponents(). It started to work when the flag was removed.

PS:Thanks to Dmitry Jemerov from IDEA community.